# Добавить многомерный массив в БАЗУ php

Tags: массивы, serialize, json, php, mysql

Есть такой массив, его нужно добавить в БАЗУ. Не могу никак сделать запрос на добавление.
Если кто знает, помогите.

```
[name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 115000917
            [1] => 115000916
            [2] => 115000915
        )

    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => Щит R1 C асмодианина 54-го уровня
            [1] => Щит R1 B асмодианина 54-го уровня
            [2] => Щит R1 A асмодианина 54-го уровня
        )

    [img] => Array
        (
            [0] => 54
            [1] => 54
            [2] => 54
        )

    [tegs] => Array
        (
            [0] => -
            [1] => -
            [2] => -
        )

Запрос такой 
INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`, `img`, `tegs`) VALUES ('.....')
```

Возможно, это не лучший вариант, но работает четко:

```
 $n = $t = ''; 
$arr = array('name'=>array(115000917,115000916,115000915),'text'=>array('Щит R1 C асмодианина 54-го уровня','Щит R1 B асмодианина 54-го уровня','Щит R1 A асмодианина 54-го уровня'));//ваш массив 
$arr_res  = array(); 
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {

     foreach($v as $key => $val) { 
        $arr_res[$key][$k] = $val; 
     }

} 
  print "<pre>"; 
  print_r($arr_res); //смотрим, что за массив получился, можно и не распечатывать

  foreach($arr_res as $val) { 
     $n = $val["name"]; 
     $t = $val["text"]; 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`) VALUES ('$n','$t')"; 
     $res = mysql_query($sql); 
  }
```

Comment: @bellator001, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`, `img`, `tegs`) VALUES ('.....')

$query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`, `img`, `tegs`) VALUES ('";
foreach ($name as $key=>$name_val){
    $query .= $name_val.','.$text[$key].','.$img[$key].','.tegs[$key];
}
$query .= "')";
```

Запрос готов, можно запускать.

Comment: @Get, там же все в один ряд выстроится, скобок всего две

Comment: Не работает этот запрос чего-то.

Comment: 
Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\bellator001\www\admin\module\module.php on line 2380

Notice: Undefined variable: text in E:\bellator001\www\admin\module\module.php on line 2380


INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`, `img`, `tegs`) VALUES ('Array,,,Array,,,Array,,,Array,,,Array,,,Array,,,')

Comment: @bellator001, судя по ошибке, переменной (массива) text не существует.

@Etki, спасибо за замечание, действительно, надо исправить код на 

$query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`, `img`, `tegs`) VALUES ";

foreach ($name as $key=>$name_val){

    $query .= '("'.name_val.'","'.$text[$key].'","'.$img[$key].'","'.$tegs[$key].'")';

    if ($key<sizeof($name)-1) {

        $query .= ',';

    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, используйте функцию [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), она будет преобразовывать ваш массив в `string`, который прекрасно добавляется в базу.

Ну, а чтобы потом вывести этот массив из базы как массив, используйте функцию [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Этот вариант мне не подходит. Я пробовал. На выходе я не могу использовать json_encode. Потому, что в той же базе есть еще данные.

Comment: @bellator001, поправьте тогда задание, чтобы полностью понимать, что у вас может быть на вход и на выход

Comment: На вход есть глобальная переменная $_POST, там храниться все это. Это все надо закинуть в базу. Только надо, чтобы 
name[0], text[0], img[0], tegs[0] были в одной строке. 
Наверное, понятно написал. )) Я в многомерных массивах плохо разбираюсь.

Comment: @bellator001, ну да, теперь понятно, что вам нужно, а то я подумал, что вам нужно массив в одну ячейку сохранять. :) А вы не пробовали поочередно внутри цикла сохранять в базу каждую строчку? То есть не цикл внутри запроса, как у @Get, а запрос внутри цикла, если нужно, могу расписать этот вариант.

Comment: Если не трудно, распиши. )

Comment: Да я уже думаю, что это не лучшее решение, потому что это будет не 1 запрос, а N запросов, где n - это количество элементов в массиве, вариант @Get оптимальнее, нужно только правильно написать всё, чтобы запрос выглядел вот так в итоге:

    INSERT INTO table VALUES('name1','text1','img1','tegs1'),('name2','text2','img2','tegs2'),('name3','text3','img3','tegs3');

Comment: $n = $t = ''; 
$arr = array('name'=>array(115000917,115000916,115000915),'text'=>array('Щит R1 C асмодианина 54-го уровня','Щит R1 B асмодианина 54-го уровня','Щит R1 A асмодианина 54-го уровня'));

$arr_res  = array(); 

foreach($arr as $k => $v) { 

     foreach($v as $key => $val) { 
        $arr_res[$key][$k] = $val; 
     } 

} 
  foreach($arr_res as $val) { 
     $n = $val["name"]; 
     $t = $val["text"]; 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `text`) VALUES ('$n','$t')"; 
     
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($sql);
  }
как Вам такое рещение?